# Issues using xlsx package to insert data from R to excel

Tags: r, excel, xlsx, rjava

I´m trying to create a new excel workbook from R to save a few small datasets using xlsx package. For some reason it was working fine, but i´m unable to do it again.

**Code to create a new workbook**

```
library("xlsx")
library("xlsxjars")
library("rJava")

file <- "marca_imei.xlsx"
wb <- loadWorkbook(file)

# The error:
# Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
#  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Your InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream
```

I´ve searched for an answer but it seems people are having the same error when importing data from excel.
I´ve tried what was recommended but it didn´t work. Here are some links for future searchers:

- http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Read-shortcuts-of-MS-Excel-files-through-R-td4677020.html
- http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Problem-with-xlsx-package-td3298470.html

`sessionInfo()`:

```
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Spain.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Spain.1252    LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Spain.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=Spanish_Spain.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] xlsx_0.5.5             xlsxjars_0.6.0         RJDBC_0.2-3            rJava_0.9-6           
 [5] DBI_0.2-7              slidifyLibraries_0.3.1 slidify_0.4            knitr_1.5             
 [9] devtools_1.4.1         scales_0.2.3           ggplot2_0.9.3.1        data.table_1.8.11     
[13] reshape2_1.2.2        

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.2-4   dichromat_2.0-0    digest_0.6.4       evaluate_0.5.1     formatR_0.10      
 [6] grid_3.0.2         gtable_0.1.2       httr_0.2           labeling_0.2       markdown_0.6.3    
[11] MASS_7.3-29        memoise_0.1        munsell_0.4.2      parallel_3.0.2     plyr_1.8          
[16] proto_0.3-10       RColorBrewer_1.0-5 RCurl_1.95-4.1     stringr_0.6.2      tools_3.0.2       
[21] whisker_0.3-2      yaml_2.1.10
```

Comment: Not an answer by any means but I prefer the XLConnect package.

Comment: Well, thanks for the comment. I´ll take a look at the package.

Comment: To possibly rule out a problem with your `xlsx` file, can you try `wb <- createWorkbook()`? If you get an error, then it is pointing to a problem with your install.

Comment: It worked. Thanks for the try anyway. `> wb <- createWorkbook()
> wb
[1] "Java-Object{Name: /xl/workbook.xml - Content Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet.main+xml}"`

Comment: I ended up using XLConnect package, it just works perfecly and is very well documented.

Answer (score 3):

Martin,

I believe the issue is that the file you are reading in is not a valid .xlsx file. Here is a code example to reproduce your problem. You can also modify the example to solve the problem. The example uses an example data set from the web (Speed Camera locations baltimore :-)).

In essence line 16 is the culprit of the error triggered on line 26 that generates the error you see.

```
Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Your InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream
```

to reproduce the error download the file "rows.csv", when you invoke read.xlsx on line 26 it triggers the error you see. To fix change line 16 to download "rows.xlsx" and rerun the script below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

# Ensure Clean Setup...
# Unload packages
if (require(xlsx)) {
        detach("package:xlsx", unload=TRUE)
}
if (require(xlsxjars)) {
        detach("package:xlsxjars", unload=TRUE)
}
# Delete Environment...
rm(list = ls())

# Delete directory
if (file.exists("data")) {
        unlink("./data", recursive = TRUE)
}

# OK - we should be in a base state setup test...

if (!require(xlsx)) {
        install.packages("xlsx")
}

if (!file.exists("data")) {
        dir.create("data")
}

# Download the file as a CSV file (Deliberate mistake) not a XLSX file
# This causes the error seen when read.xlsx is invoked...
# To fix replace rows.csv with rows.xlsx

if (!file.exists("data/cameras.xlsx")) {
        fileUrl <- "https://data.baltimorecity.gov/api/views/dz54-2aru/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD"
        download.file(fileUrl, destfile = "./data/cameras.xlsx", method = "curl")
}

list.files("./data")

# Now we check the file exists and read in the data...
# read.xlsx will throw the java error as the file downloaded is not a valid excel file...

if (!file.exists(".data/cameraData.xlsx")) {
        cameraData.xlsx <- read.xlsx("./data/cameras.xlsx", sheetIndex=1, header = TRUE)
}

head(cameraData.xlsx)
```

Here is the example output:

1. Load rows.csv...

   > source('test.R')
   >   Loading required package: xlsx
   >   Loading required package: xlsxjars
   >     % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
   >                                    Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
   >     0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0100  9294  100  9294    0     0  33870      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 33796
   >       Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
   >         java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Your InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream

   now we replace rows.csv with rows.xlsx...

```html
> source('test.R', echo=TRUE)

> #!/usr/bin/env Rscript
> 
> # Ensure Clean Setup...
> # Unload packages
> if (require(xlsx)) {
+         detach("package:xlsx", unload=TRUE)
+ }

> if (require(xlsxjars)) {
+         detach("package:xlsxjars", unload=TRUE)
+ }

> # Delete Environment...
> rm(list = ls())

> # Delete directory
> if (file.exists("data")) {
+         unlink("./data", recursive = TRUE)
+ }

> # OK - we should be in a base state setup test...
> 
> if (!require(xlsx)) {
+         install.packages("xlsx")
+ }
Loading required package: xlsx
Loading required package: xlsxjars

> if (!file.exists("data")) {
+         dir.create("data")
+ }

> # Download the file as a CSV file (Deliberate mistake) not a XLSX file
> # This causes the error seen when read.xlsx is invoked...
> # To fix replac .... [TRUNCATED] 
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0100  9923  100  9923    0     0  48559      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 48642

> list.files("./data")
[1] "cameras.xlsx"

> # Now we check the file exists and read in the data...
> # read.xlsx will throw the java error as the file downloaded is not a valid excel file...
> .... [TRUNCATED] 

> head(cameraData.xlsx)
                         address direction      street  crossStreet               intersection                      Location.1
1       S CATON AVE & BENSON AVE       N/B   Caton Ave   Benson Ave     Caton Ave & Benson Ave (39.2693779962, -76.6688185297)
2       S CATON AVE & BENSON AVE       S/B   Caton Ave   Benson Ave     Caton Ave & Benson Ave (39.2693157898, -76.6689698176)
3 WILKENS AVE & PINE HEIGHTS AVE       E/B Wilkens Ave Pine Heights Wilkens Ave & Pine Heights  (39.2720252302, -76.676960806)
4        THE ALAMEDA & E 33RD ST       S/B The Alameda      33rd St     The Alameda  & 33rd St (39.3285013141, -76.5953545714)
5        E 33RD ST & THE ALAMEDA       E/B      E 33rd  The Alameda      E 33rd  & The Alameda (39.3283410623, -76.5953594625)
6        ERDMAN AVE & N MACON ST       E/B      Erdman     Macon St         Erdman  & Macon St (39.3068045671, -76.5593167803)
>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible the problem is with Java, not XLConnect.  Be sure you have Java installed by taking the test on the Java site -- it will confirm Java is correctly installed.  Then make sure R knows the path to find the jre.dll or something like that file name for what is crucial.

Second, here is the code I have been using for a year, without the error message you got.
If it helps you ....

```
read.xls <- function(filename, sheetnumber=1, sheetname=NULL, forceConversion=TRUE, startCol=0,  stringsAsFactors=TRUE) {
wb <- loadWorkbook(filename)
if (is.null(sheetname)) sheetname = getSheets(wb)[sheetnumber]
df <- readWorksheet(wb, sheet=sheetname, forceConversion=forceConversion, startCol=startCol)
if (stringsAsFactors) {
ischar <- sapply(df, class) == "character"
for (i in 1:length(df)) {
if (ischar[i]) df[,i] <- factor(df[,i])
}
}
df
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i´ll try this. However, the error comes when using xlsx.

Comment: I´ve tried to read an excel file and got this: `> read.xls("1_imei.xslx")
Error in loadWorkbook(filename) : Cannot find 1_imei.xslx
Called from: top level 
Browse[1]> c`

Comment: this is the problem: `wb <- loadWorkbook(filename)`