# Error reading an xlsx file from Dropbox using the R package 'repmis'

Tags: r, excel, dropbox

I need to be able to read a sheet from an xlsx workbook into R for use in a Shiny app. (I know it should be a csv file, but that is unfortunately not my decision...).**(Edited to add: The file I need to read is on dropbox)** I am trying to use the repmis package. The code I have tried is simply:

```
library('repmis')
library('xlsx')
lnk<-"https://www.dropbox.com/s/pzyt86pguko3xg6/TestBook.xlsx?dl=0"
my_data<-source_XlsxData(lnk, sheet="MainData", startRow=1)
```

Unfortunately I get the following error message:

```
Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  :
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Your InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream
```

I have no idea what it means... :|

Comment: Have you considered using `readr` or `readxl` package?

Comment: I hadn't come across those two. I'm not sure they work with dropbox? (I forgot to specify, that the file I need to access is in Dropbox

Comment: Ah I see. You need to get the data from dropbox and import in R.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22078092/issues-using-xlsx-package-to-insert-data-from-r-to-excel) may be related to your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think a recent update removed the ability to read data files stored on Dropbox from within R. I will go look for confirmation, and delete my comment otherwise.

*Source: Ran into the same issue myself a couple of months ago*

**UPDATE:** Confirmation of dropped support within the github package https://github.com/christophergandrud/repmis/commit/f85469f38c6f4e4a5735ecc888b4263b969d4e22

Comment: Thanks drsh - does that apply to the `source_XlsxData` command as well?

Comment: I don't have access to R to do some testing right now but it looks from the code files that source_XlsxData works fine for public links, but Dropbox personal folders seem to be off-limits. See here for more info, as well as the code files themselves: https://github.com/christophergandrud/repmis/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Thanks for that information. I'll see what I can figure out.