# Shiny R - source script that updates data frame - error in .jcall

Tags: r, dataframe, import, shiny, xlsx

I am trying to build a shiny application that visualizes data using ggplot2. I want the app to be adaptive to new data that is copied as .xlsx files to a dropbox folder.

I wrote a script to read all excel files in the dropbox folder and to tranform them to a data frame (.Rda). The script works perfectly fine but when I try to source it from my shiny app, the application breaks down. Below you can find my app, the script to import data and the error that occurs.

This is an example of my App:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

load("df.Rda")

ui <- bootstrapPage(
    actionButton(inputId = "button", label="Upload new Data"),
    plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

observeEvent(input$button,{
   source("PreparationServer.R")
})

output$plot <- renderPlot(
  ggplot(df, aes(City, Total.Inc.VAT))+
   geom_bar(stat="identity")
 )
}
```

shinyApp(ui, server)

This is the script I use to transform the excel files to .Rda:

```
###Load required libraries
library(xlsx)

##########################################################################
## Load Excel Sheets as Data Frames 
files <- (Sys.glob("c:///Users/T400/Dropbox/HTM (1)/*.xlsx"))

listOfFiles <- lapply(files, function(x) read.xlsx(x, 
                                               sheetIndex = 1,
                                               colIndex = 1:19, 
                                               header=TRUE, 
                                               encoding = 'UTF-8'))

df <- as.data.frame(listOfFiles[1])

for(i in 2:length(listOfFiles)){
  df_temp <- as.data.frame(listOfFiles[i])
  df <- rbind(df, df_temp)
}

save(df, file="c://Users/T400/Dropbox/HTM (1)/df.Rda")

##########################################################################
```

I am getting the following error when I try to source my script from the shiny app:

```
Warning: Error in .jcall: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Your 
InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream
```

Comment: Perhaps try `source("PreparationServer.R", local = TRUE)`  Also, please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39339492/error-reading-an-xlsx-file-from-dropbox-using-the-r-package-repmis)  Or else you could try with `library(readxl)`

Comment: This error generally occurs on reading _invalid xlsx_ files, check this and also give [XLConnect](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XLConnect/index.html) a try, it's preferred for reading excel data

Comment: Thank your very much, I used `library(readxl)` and now its working!