# Problem faced in reading an xlsx file in R

Tags: java, r, xlsx, data-analysis, coursera-api

I am currently using R on a Windows 10 laptop.

I have downloaded an xlsx file in the working directory. After loading the `xlsx` package, whenever I am trying to read the file using the `read.xlsx`, it is showing me this error :

> Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Your InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: Did you have a look to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22078092/issues-using-xlsx-package-to-insert-data-from-r-to-excel) ?

Comment: You can use `openxlsx` package.

Comment: You can use `library("readxl")` and read file as `read_excel("file.xlsx")`